# Remove Cookie From Request Headers of Ajax Except Some Of

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies

**Problem:** A issue is whatever I have set in a cookie's it all has automatic sent to ajax request.

**Expected:** I want to send only "token", "userName", "lang" into a ajax header.

**Tried:** I have tried to convert all cookies to javascript localStorage except "token", "userName", "lang" and it's working fine but for this I want to change in entire system. so I don't like

I want minimum change in my code, It is possible ?

**Note:** Please don't prefer any third party plugin like (Cookie Monster).       Because client don't like to implement any plugin.

My Common Ajax Call. (Haven't set any cookie)

```
$.ajax({
        url         : ajax_url,
        dataType    : "json",
        type        : method,
        data        : params,
        cache       : false,
        crossDomain : true,
        async       : aSync,
        contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        headers: {
            "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"
        },
        error       : function(data, status, error) {
            (ajaxObject.loader == true) ? unblockUI(loaderWrapper) : "";
            failure_callback(error);
        },
        success     : function(data) {

alert(data);

        }
    });
```

My Common Method For Set Cookies. (After Login)

```
function login(returnObject) {
        setCookie("token",returnObject.token,1);
        setCookie("userName",returnObject.userName,1);
        setCookie("lang",returnObject.lang,1);
        setCookie("siteName",siteName,1);
        setCookie("gridMaxWidth",gridMaxWidth,1);
        setCookie("environment",returnObject.environment,1);
        setCookie("version",returnObject.version,1);
        setCookie("typeAheadCharCount",returnObject.typeAheadCharCount,1);
        setCookie("warningApplyAllLimit",returnObject.warningApplyAllLimit,1);
    }
```

Common Set Cookie Function.

```
/* Set cookies */
function setCookie(cookieKey, cookieValue, cookieExpiry) {
     if (cookieExpiry != -1) {
         document.cookie = cookieKey + "=" + cookieValue + "; path=/";
     } else {
      document.cookie = cookieKey + "=" + cookieValue + "; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 UTC; path=/";
     }
}
```

Comment: All cookies is sent with all http requests. If you do not want to send a cookie, you need to delete it. By this smells very strongly of an X/Y problem. Why is it a problem that you send the other cookies?

Comment: 1. Yes.. It will automatic sent into all http requests.
2. It will not create problem but cookie length is very large to we dont want to send this.

Comment: It was not a question. When you set a cookie it WILL be sent with all http requests even images. If you do not want that, you need to delete the cookie before. The question: WHY are the other cookies a problem for you when you perform your axax

Comment: 1. I have added setCookie() on my question, 
2. it will sent only ajax request (Not img, file etc..)
3. if I delete it then how can I access again ? that all cookies set when login the user.

4. It's not create problem but as I said above it will large data so no need to send every time on ajax

Comment: I have updated my answer. It IS an X/Y problem since your config object needs to use session/localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration does not belong in a cookie. It belongs in a sessionStorage for the session and localStorage if the user wants to have the same settings next time they visit

That said, when you set a cookie it WILL be sent with all http requests even images residing on the same server of the code that set the cookie.

You cannot change an Ajax request to have less cookies unless you send it to a different server or path (cookies are only sent to the same origin and path)

If you do not want to send so many cookies, then

- Use sessionStorage or localStorage for setting values
- Don't set cookies when not needed and delete them when no longer needed.
- Change the ajax request to a different server or path than what is in the cookie

Comment: 1. Does it mean, It will not modify if a request is going to the same server? 
2. It's not possible to delete before ajax, because I have used everywhere. (Just remove from ajax request header).    
3. Yes, localStorage is one of the option but As I told need to change the entire project.

Comment: If you set the cookie with path=/somepath, then an ajax request to /otherpath will not send the cookies. If you implement CORS and send to xxx.myserver.com then cookies set at yyy.myserver.com will not be sent